# Seeking Android equivalent to iOS App Download Prompt

Tags: android, call-to-action

I'm wondering if such a pattern exists for android users. See attached image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Sure, I would like to find out if there's a convention / pattern that you would find similarly in the image link provided that prompts the user about the app on the Android mobile web experience. I'm having trouble finding it on the Android pattern library online.

Comment: Don't think Android has a pattern like this. How does the iOS one work?

Comment: they place a banner / cta below the search / URL bar.

Comment: @Designedbyjay, your question text asks about a download prompt, but the image you've included suggests that the app was already downloaded and shows a prompt to open it. Which type of prompt are you asking about?

Answer (score 4):

This question regarding the iOS smart app banner on Android has been discussed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168706/creating-an-android-smart-app-banner

Comment: This says how to achieve it, but not whether it's a common pattern on Android or why to avoid/do it.